# Crear base de datos en PostgreSQL desde SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Se está realizando un aplicativo en .NET para registrar (inventariar) bases de datos (provenientes de SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL y Oracle), usuarios y credenciales en tablas de SQL Server, lo que se desea hacer adicionalmente es que este aplicativo no solo registre, sino que también genere la sentencia DDL para la creación de la misma dependiendo del manejador, esto es sencillo, lo que no encuentro es como ejecutar estas sentencias desde SQL Server a otro manejador.

En resumen quisiera saber si es posible ejecutar sentencias DDL en PostgreSQL u otro manejador desde SQL Server, o se hace necesario crear una conexión del aplicativo directamente con la base de datos en cuestión (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle). Aunque de existir la forma de hacerlo quisiera ahorrarme el tiempo de estar descargando los drivers e implementarlos en el aplicativo.

***Nota:*** Ya se cuenta con los drivers de PostgreSQL y MySQL para hacer consultas desde SQL Server vía linkservers, pero no encuentro la forma de crear una base de datos de esa misma forma.

Cualquier sugerencia me sería muy útil.

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mediante OPENQUERY, pero eso es algo que muchos administradores evitan por cuestiones de seguridad. Lo ideal es hacer la conexión desde .NET para apuntar al servidor de base de datos correcto.

Comment: Espero que hayas considerado que la sintaxis y los tipos de dato son distintos según cada manejador de base de datos.

Comment: Hola Luis, podrías decirme como usar el OPENQUERY para crear bases de datos, por que solo lo he usado para la sentencia SELECT.

Comment: Fue mi error, se hace con [EXEC AT](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/)